# Turn off automatic figure numbering

Tags: floats, formatting

I have this code:

```
 \begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{ex.png}
  \caption{Fig. 6: example.}
\end{figure*}
```

But it is the 6th figure of my report. I automatically also see Figure 1 before Fig.6, I guess because this is the first time I use figure*.

I use figure* because the rest of my document it 2 columns and this allows me to have a 2 column figure. How do i turn off this auto numbering?

Comment: Don't use `\caption`.

Comment: How do I add a caption to the figure? I just want to turn automatic numbering off. Currently the caption for this figure looks like: Figure 1: Fig. 6: example.

Comment: It is \caption that makes the number. Don't the earlier figures have captions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX will automatically insert a label and a number whenever you say `\caption`, if you don't want this, either don't use the word `\caption` or use `\caption*` from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image}
 \caption*{Fig. 6: example.}
 % Or just:
 % Fig. 6: example.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]